# Possible fundamental misunderstanding on how Factories work?

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I am trying to write an Angular factory that basically opens a websocket, listens to connections and prints messages it receives from the server

I crafted my factory this way:

```
angular.module('zmApp.controllers')
.factory('EventServer', 
 [ '$websocket',function 
 ( $websocket) {

    function start()
    {

        console.log("*************FACTORY EVENT SERVER*************");
        var dataStream;
        console.log ("FACTORY webSocketStart: attempting to start a WSS connection");

        dataStream =$websocket("wss://<server>:9000/");


        dataStream.onMessage = function(message) {
            console.log("SERVICE GOT WEBSOCKET MESSAGE:" + message.data);
        };


     return {
         start:start
     };
}])
```

Here are my doubts:

- How do I make sure this factory gets "Started" and receives
  messages like its supposed to irrespective of which app
  controller/view I am in? I had assumed by including this factory in
  index.html, it will automatically get invoked. Not so. Even if I invoke EventServer.start() in app.run, I can see the socket initializing and connecting but I never receive an onMessage callback
- If I rename the "Factory" to a "service" it does get started automatically when the app runs  but
  when I move to another controller/view it stops receiving messages (same as factory)

My goal is to write a factory that receives web socket messages. I'm probably getting confused on how to do this and keep it independent of what state/view my app is in.

And here is the odd part: If I start the web socket socket with a reconnect option on and I bring down the server, I can see the web socket trying to reconnect - so I know the connection object - dataStream is not getting destroyed.

I know $websocket is working because if I create a web socket inside a controller for a view I am in, it works perfectly and the onMessage is received.

What I can't seem to get is how to push this into a view independent factory.

I'd appreciate advice.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Factories are singletons, meaning a new instance gets created each time you inject it into a controller or another factory.

It sounds like you are not injecting the factory where you want to use it. The controller you want to use it in should look like:

```
angular
.module('zmApp.controllers')
.controller('YourController', ['EventServer', function(EventServer) {
   EventServer.start // to access the method in your factory
}]);
```

You need to do this for each controller or factory you want to use `EventServer` in.

Comment: I am injecting it. Here is a sample controller http://pastebin.com/UQYp4Cf9 --> the factory onMessage never gets called. Interestingly the onMessage of this controller does get called even when you navigate out of it!

Comment: You could just use the `$websocket` service directly if you are only calling methods on that service. It's a service so can be injected where you like. Is creating `EventServer` factory adding anything different to what `$websocket` is already doing?

Comment: Thanks. So right now this is a stub. In future it will expand  more and this web socket connection is going to be Independant of application state. Hence the urge to make the factory work.